# facing an issue while connecting nodejs app(container a) and sql server (container b)

Tags: node.js, sql-server, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

web docker file

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /app 
COPY package*.json ./ 


RUN npm install 
COPY . . 
EXPOSE 3000 
CMD ["npm", "start"
```

db docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

EXPOSE 1433
```

docker compose file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    build: ./db
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: mahe@123
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      MSSQL_PID: Developer
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    restart: always

  web:
    build: ./web
    environment:
      DB_CONNECTION_STRING: Server=localhost;Database=Bitespeed;User Id=sa;Password=mahe@123;
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: on-failure
```

dbconfig.js file

```
const config = {
  user: 'sa',
  password: 'mahe@123',
  server: 'localhost',
  database: 'Bitespeed',

  options: {
    enableArithAort: true,
    trustServerCertificate:true
  },
  port: 1433
}

module.exports = config;
```

server.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const sql = require('mssql');
const config = require("./dbconfig")
require('dotenv').config()

const port = process.env.PORT

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

const mainRouter = require('./router')
app.use('/api',mainRouter)

function connectWithRetry(){
    return sql.connect(config,(err) => {
 
         if (err) {
             console.log(`Connection to DB failed, retry in 5s `,err.message)
             sql.close()
             setTimeout(connectWithRetry(), 5000);
         }
         else {
             console.log('Connected to SQL Server successfully');
         }
     }); 
 }

 connectWithRetry()

app.listen(port , ()=>{
    console.log("app is listening on port " + port)
})
```

can any plase help me what is the error. and i am getting the  following error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGHsF.png)

and my db is running fine..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl3bH.png)

can any one help me with this..

i am expecting my node app will connect to the sql server.

Comment: `localhost` is within the container. Either use the other container's name/IP or the host's name/ip

Comment: no...its not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, `localhost` will point to the container itself (`web`). You can specify the docker-compose alias of the database service (`db`) instead in your config:

```
const config = {
  ...
  server: 'db',
  ...
  port: 1433
}
```

Since you are also setting an environment variable `DB_CONNECTION_STRING` in your `docker-compose.myml` which seems to overwrite your settings, you probably also need to change the "localhost" in that environment variable:

```
web:
  build: ./web
  environment:
    DB_CONNECTION_STRING: Server=db;Database=Bitespeed;User Id=sa;Password=mahe@123;`
```

Comment: No its not working, i am getting the same error.

Comment: I see that you are also setting an environment variable `DB_CONNECTION_STRING`. Is this overwriting your settings and, if yes, did you also change the "localhost" in that environment variable?

Comment: that is so helpful, my node app able to communicate with the sql server. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad that it helped! I will update my answer to integrate this comment. It would be nice if you could accept the answer if it helped to solve your issue.

Comment: Rob..! can you help me, how to run the MSSQL queries to create tables as soon as the db image has been created?

Comment: You could use an entrypoint script for that purpose. See the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039052/how-to-run-a-setup-script-on-a-docker-sql-server-image). Alternatively, you could use something like stored procedures built in in MS SQL Server, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334791/run-ms-sql-server-script-on-startup) for example.

Comment: no rob its not working , i have been trying from last 3 days

Comment: What exactly is not working? Can you provide some more details? Which steps have you taken and is there an error message? Or maybe open a new question?

Comment: hi rob i have created new question , you can find this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76634807/failed-to-run-a-setup-script-on-a-docker-sql-server-image